# Finding the Projection without using projection matrix always but to use some symmetry

Tags: geometry, symmetry

I am interested in finding the t2' with the help of t1, t1' and t2. Actually I am using some projection matrix T (this will be used to project point x and y which is clear in the Image attached) on x and y to get the points t1 and t2. Again I have to use the matrix T on x' and y' to find the t1' and t2'. But I don't want to exactly use the matrix T to do this just to avoid the lots of multiplication.

Is there any way to find t2' with the help of t1' and the result followed in the case of t1 and t1'.

```
T*x = t1
T*y = t2
t*x' = t1'
```

I am attaching picture for better visibility of the question.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have $y'=y+x'-x$ you also have

$$t_2'=Ty'=T(y+x'-x)=Ty+Tx'-Tx=t_2+t_1'-t_1$$